# Creating forms through drupal UI

Tags: forms, drupal-7

Is it possible to create forms using drupal's UI (without coding) or we must have to code using Form API to create forms??? I've managed to add some text fields and check-boxes but its not a complete form and I can't find anyway to add buttons to it? I am new to drupal so don't know much about it. Any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Webform Module](http://drupal.org/project/webform)

> Webform is the module for making surveys in Drupal. After a
>   submission, users may be sent an e-mail "receipt" as well as sending a
>   notification to administrators. Results can be exported into Excel or
>   other spreadsheet applications. Webform also provides some basic
>   statistical review and has and extensive API for expanding its
>   features.
>
> Some good examples could be contests, personalized contact forms, or
>   petitions. Each of these could have a customized form for end-users to
>   fill out. If you need to build a lot of customized, one-off forms,
>   Webform is a more suitable solution than creating content types and
>   using CCK or Field module.

Comment: The fields Web forms provide are almost the same as CCK. All I want to is to add a submit button and an image preview area. The rest of the fields are created successfully.